# Give an L-formula ϕ(x, y) that defines the less-than relation < over R in M.?

Tags: logic

Let L = {+, ·, P} where + and · are binary function symbols and P is a unary predicate symbol, and let M be an L-structure where its domain |M| is the 
set R of real numbers, + and · are the usual addition and multiplication over R 
respectively, and P = {r ∈ R | r > 0}.

(i) Give an L-formula ϕ(x) that defines the set {1} ⊂ R in M.

(ii) Give an L-formula ϕ(x, y) that defines the less-than relation < over R in M.

(iii) Give an L-formula ϕ(x) that defines the set {√2} ⊂ R in M.

(iv) Give an L-formula ϕ4(x) that defines the interval [1,√2) ⊂ R in M.

My formula for part (i) is: ∃x∀y(x·y ≡ y), and (iii): ∃x(Px ∧ x·x ≡ 2)

Is this what the question is asking for? If so, I'm unable to answer part (iii) and therefore (iv). Thank you!

Comment: For (ii) : $x < y$ **iff** $\exists z(P(z) \land y=x+z)$.

Comment: You're looking for a formula with a free variable in (i).  So letting $\phi_1(x)=\forall y (x\cdot y = y)$ is good.  Or $\phi_1(x) = (P(x) \wedge x\cdot x = x)$ would work also.  How can you tell if $x < y$?  One way is to say that $x + z = y$ for some $z > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Answers in the form of guidance as it seems like what you're asking for:

A formula $\varphi(x)$ which defines a set needs to be open. We say that $\varphi(x)$ defines the set ${1}$ if $M\models \varphi(c)$ if and only if $1=c \in R$. Thus your answer to (i) is not really correct but it is if you remove the quantifier for $x$.

i.e.  $\forall y (x \cdot y = y)$ is a good answer.

Regarding your answer to (iii) you have a problem even if you remove the quantifier, since $2$ is not a constant in the language, this $\varphi$ you have created is not an $L-$formula. Remember that L formulas use only symbols from the language, together with quantifiers, variables and connectives.

Instead use the following strategy for (iii): Let $\varphi(x)$ be the formula you used to define ${1}$ in exercise (i). The formula $\forall y(\varphi(y) \rightarrow y+y = ...)$ then say that "for each element satisfying $\varphi$ (i.e. only $1$) 1+1 equals something. Thus we may using this construction say the number 2 without having it in the language. Combine this way with your thoughts on the formula for (iii) and you get the answer.

For (ii): Expressing that $x< y$ is the same as saying that there exists a positive number $z$ such that $x+z = y$. Now use the relation P to express this.

For (iv): combine the other exercises together to state that $x$ is less than $\sqrt(2)$ and greater than or equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ove!

I think these make sense.

φ1(x): ∀y(x⋅y = y)

φ2(x,y): ∃z(P(z) ∧ (x+z = y))

φ3(x): ∀y(φ1(y) → ((y+y) = (x⋅x))) ∧ P(x)

φ4(x): (∀y∀z(φ3(y) ∧ φ2(x,y) ∧ φ1(z) ∧ φ2(z,y))) ∨ φ1(x)

Please correct me if I'm wrong! :)

Comment: Yes, $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ and $\varphi_3$ all seem correct. However $\varphi_4$ needs an implication instead of conjuctions everywhere. Right now the left part say that all elements (y and z) are $\sqrt{2}$ or $1$, thus the disjunction is only true if $x=1$. Instead say that for each element $y,z$ IF $y=1$ and $z=\sqrt{2}$, then $x$ is in the interval betwen them (notice the implication in this statement).